# Install specific adb version on Linux

Tags: android, adb

I would like use specific adb version for connect devices. For connect external emulator, i try to use `adb connect localhost:5555`, i've this result :

```
[adb]: adb server version (36) doesn't match this client (40); killing...
[adb]: * daemon started successfully
```

For install adb, i use `apt install adb` but i've only version 1.0.36.

Anyone know if i can install and use version 1.0.40 of adb ?

Comment: Why not using the one shipped with the Android SDK?

Comment: It's on 2 docker container, the version is not the same :/

Comment: What I mean is that the `adb` shipped with the latest Android SDK is version `1.0.40`, why are you installing it with `apt` instead of using that one?

Answer (score 13):

In my Dockerfile I use:

```
  mkdir -p /usr/local/android-sdk \
  && cd /usr/local/android-sdk/ \
  && curl -OL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip \
  && unzip platform-tools-latest-linux.zip \
  && rm -f platform-tools-latest-linux.zip \
  && ln -s /usr/local/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb \
  && export PATH=/usr/local/android-sdk/platform-tools:${PATH} \
  && echo "export PATH=/usr/local/android-sdk/platform-tools:${PATH}" >> /etc/profile \
```

Answer (score 8):

You can download specific version of the platform tools by using

```
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r<specific-version>-linux.zip
```

But there is little correlation between platform-tool version and adb version.

For example `platform-tools_r29.0.5-linux` has adb version 41. You can take a look at release notes for the particular adb version you want.

After downloading, follow @lojza answer for setting up soft links for your system.

Comment: So how does one get the specific version without trial and error. There has got to be a release note or inventory spec some where. This is the new millennia, right?

Answer (score 2):

For this problem, the link above may be invalid. But I found the [github repo](https://github.com/awake558/adb-win) for specific platform-tools including all OS. So just download the version related to specific adb(for example, 28.0.1 corresponding to ADB 1.0.40) . Then unzip & set environment.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android SDK Platform-Tools from Android Studio, then go to "/Sdk/platform-tools/" directory. 
Run `./adb --version` 
The same way you can maintain multiple adb version file in different places.

Answer (score 0):

This following steps can be done only for Linux.

- Download the specific adb version from Android SDK.
- Locate the adb file from Android/Sdk/platform-tools.
- Then move the file  to **sudo mv adb /usr/bin/adb**.
- After relocating the adb, go to /usr/bin/adb.
- By giving read and write permission , **sudo chmod +x ./adb** .

Specific adb version is been installed.

To check the adb version, use **adb --version**

Answer (score 0):

Since this ADB server version (XX) doesn't match this client (YY); killing... seems to be a very prominent question, let me present the quite straight forward solution - I actually wonder why it wasn't answered anywhere else or at least, I couldn't find it. To find the version of ADB you are using, type adb version to get something like:

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.5-6877874
Installed as D:\Setups\XXXXX\Lineage FP3\platform-tools_30.0.5(ADB_1.0.41)\adb.exe
```

The Android version simply doesn't match the adb version. **Android 11** for example uses the API 30 and ADB 41. **Android 10 (API 29)** and that phone needs ADB 40. You can check your Android version to **find the corresponding ADB version** to get or easily read the error message above to find XX (in this case 40).

I was able to find ADB version 1.0.40 from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AndroidSDK.PlatformTools.ADB/1.0.40) and [here](https://www.evofiles.net/download/sdk-platform-tools-for-windows-latest-version/). it works like a charm:

```
D:\Setups\XXXXX\Lineage FP3\platform-tools_28.0.1(ADB_1.0.40)>adb devices
List of devices attached
A2XXXXXXXXX1    unauthorized.
```