# ADB install-multi-package / Wanting to install APK's with separate packages as fast as possible

Tags: android, adb

I can see the official docs for `adb install` https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#move

but where are the official docs for `adb install-multiple` & `adb install-multi-package` pls?

I only found clues of their existence from here: https://adbshell.com/commands/adb-install (especially `install-multi-package` is what I wanted to give a go)

[image]

I get "unknown command" when I try it,

[image]

and there's a mention of a fix for it in the platform tools release:

[image]

Can anyone explain it's use?
What version supports it?
And any more docs links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best docs is code. Check https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/b581ce93bbd8f900b8e2ff63b80872f2748e32a4/adb/client/commandline.cpp#150

```
    " install-multiple [-lrtsdpg] [--instant] PACKAGE...\n"
    "     push multiple APKs to the device for a single package and install them\n"
    " install-multi-package [-lrtsdpg] [--instant] PACKAGE...\n"
    "     push one or more packages to the device and install them atomically\n"
    "     -r: replace existing application\n"
    "     -t: allow test packages\n"
    "     -d: allow version code downgrade (debuggable packages only)\n"
    "     -p: partial application install (install-multiple only)\n"
    "     -g: grant all runtime permissions\n"
    "     --instant: cause the app to be installed as an ephemeral install app\n"
    "     --no-streaming: always push APK to device and invoke Package Manager as separate steps\n"
    "     --streaming: force streaming APK directly into Package Manager\n"
    "     --fastdeploy: use fast deploy\n"
    "     --no-fastdeploy: prevent use of fast deploy\n"
    "     --force-agent: force update of deployment agent when using fast deploy\n"
    "     --date-check-agent: update deployment agent when local version is newer and using fast deploy\n"
    "     --version-check-agent: update deployment agent when local version has different version code and using fast deploy\n"
```

I'm affraid ubuntu adb version is little bit outdated. Install latest platform tools. How to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55724130/2235381